# MacBook Pro 13" is restarting after RAM upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, reboot

I have upgraded my MBP from 4GB (2x2GB) to 16GB (2x8GB) SO-DIMMs. After upgrading it keeps restarting continuously.

Here is the new RAM detail:
[Kingston Mac Memory 8GB DDR3L-1600(PC3-12800](http://www.amazon.in/Kingston-DDR3L-1600-PC3-12800-KTA-MB1600L-8G/dp/B00ET1J0QG/254-7172131-5356860?ie=UTF8&ref_=cm_sw_r_wa_api_KF6JxbVP9RJCB)) SO-DIMM 1.35V (KTA-MB1600L/8G).

This screen appears before restarting:

[image]

Apple Macbook Pro MD101HN/A 13-inch Laptop (mid 2012)

- Core i5
- 4GB
- 500GB
- Mac OS Mavericks

Comment: Chances are, you have the wrong RAM.  What is the model and/or year of your MacBook Pro?  It could also be defective RAM, but let's check to make sure you have the right memory for your particular MacBook.

Comment: Apple Macbook Pro MD101HN/A 13-inch Laptop (Core i5/4GB/500GB/Mac OS Mavericks/Intel HD Graphics), Silver https://www.amazon.in/dp/B00DKMCB20/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_Ef8Jxb7C3WFQ6

Comment: This is the model i own.

Comment: Please post those details to the ***question***.  It helps when this information is provided with the question itself.  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.    Take a look at [How To Ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) on writing a good question.

Comment: Can you run [Apple Hardware Test (AHT)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold the D key while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter connected?  Also, remove one of the models and try to boot.  If it fails again, swap the modules and test again.  Post your results to the original question.

Comment: When you edit your question, you should not just link to Amazon, also list the model number and which version of the Mac it is (mid 2012?). Can you also tell us what you did with the RAM, did you leave in one of the original 2GB RAM sticks and replace one of them with the 8GB stick? You're supposed to have them both the same. Try putting your old RAM back in and see what happens.

Comment: Does that model support 16 GB? My late 2011 13" MBP only supports 8GB total ram. Either way, try putting the old RAM back in to see if it fixes it so we'll better know where the problem is.

Comment: @kal-al - It's a mid 2012 (after some digging).  It support 16GB

Comment: Does it work okay with only one of the new pieces of RAM and have you tried separately with both new pieces of RAM one at a time? (Not using the old RAM while testing the new RAM one at a time.) Also test separately in each bank.

Comment: Thank you guys,i need to take it back to Service centre to replace the old RAM to check if it works.I'll be able to post about it tomorrow.For information AHT test didn't work as my system got stuck in middle of the process.

Comment: @Arun_ Try removing one of the RAM modules you installed.

Comment: One of the RAM was defective.Thank you all for your patience and help.